# Getting an error in jenkins - maven project when building

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Getting the below error in maven jenkins web project 
[image]

Below is my pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/versions-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
 <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>  
    </plugins>
    <finalName>MyWebAppMaven</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

When ever i try to build in jenkins it throws that error which is given above.
My project is simple web project, and my jenkins config for proj is as below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the exact command line call you use?

Comment: i have added clean install...just tried all these options

Comment: the "goals" setting is wrong, a file path (`D:/apache-maven-3.6.3`) is not allowed there. Valid maven goals are `clean`, `install` etc.